# Drawing glitches when using CreateGraphics rather than Paint event handler for custom drawing

Tags: c#, winforms

I've written a Windows Forms app where I do custom drawing on a `Panel` using `Control.CreateGraphics()`.  Here's what my `Form` looks like at startup:

[image: blank form with Draw! button]

The custom drawing is performed on the top panel in the `Click` event handler of the "Draw!" button.  Here's my button click handler:

```
private void drawButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    using (Graphics g = drawPanel.CreateGraphics())
    {
        g.SmoothingMode = System.Drawing.Drawing2D.SmoothingMode.AntiAlias;
        g.Clear(Color.White);
        Size size = drawPanel.ClientSize;
        Rectangle bounds = drawPanel.ClientRectangle;
        bounds.Inflate(-10, -10);
        g.FillEllipse(Brushes.LightGreen, bounds);
        g.DrawEllipse(Pens.Black, bounds);
    }
}
```

After a click on `drawButton`, the form looks like this:

[image: form with green filled ellipse]

Success!

But when I shrink the form by dragging a corner...

[image: same form, shrunk to partially hide ellipse]

...and expand it back to its original size,

[image: form with missing graphics on right and bottom]

part of what I drew is gone!

This also happens when I drag part of the window offscreen...

[image: form partially offscreen]

...and drag it back onscreen:

[image: form back onscreen but with half of graphics missing]

If I minimize the window and restore it, the whole image is erased:

[image: blank form like first image]

What is causing this?  How can I make it so the graphics I draw are persistent?

Note: I've created this self-answered question so I have a canonical Q/A to direct users to, as this is a common scenario that's hard to search for if you don't already know the cause of the problem.

Comment: For a canonical Q&A, don't you think all the images are a bit much? The question itself could be *seriously* trimmed down here, getting the focus on the answer. This is a very simple problem to describe—I draw stuff but it goes away.

Comment: Well, I think they help illustrate the common symptoms, but you're free to downvote.

Comment: Downvoting doesn't fix the problem. I had not found this question before, but this is something I need to start using...often. There are a *lot* of questions that need to be closed as duplicates of this, but it bothers me that the question is so long, making what should be a simple issue needlessly complicated. Makes it hard to get to the information that people want. I would have just edited it, but I noticed that you didn't make it community wiki even though you intended it to be a canonical Q&A, so I didn't want to just impose.

Answer (score 11):

## TL;DR:

Don't do your drawing in response to a one-time UI event with `Control.CreateGraphics`.  Instead, register a `Paint` event handler for the control on which you want to paint, and do your drawing with the `Graphics` object passed via the `PaintEventArgs`.

If you want to paint only after a button click (for example), in your `Click` handler, set a boolean flag indicating that the button has been clicked and then call `Control.Invalidate()`.  Then do your rendering conditionally in the `Paint` handler.

Finally, if your control's contents should change with the size of the control, register a `Resize` event handler and call Invalidate() there too.

Example code:

```
private bool _doCustomDrawing = false;

private void drawPanel_Paint(object sender, PaintEventArgs e)
{
    if (_doCustomDrawing)
    {
        Graphics g = e.Graphics;
        g.SmoothingMode = System.Drawing.Drawing2D.SmoothingMode.AntiAlias;
        g.Clear(Color.White);
        Size size = drawPanel.ClientSize;
        Rectangle bounds = drawPanel.ClientRectangle;
        bounds.Inflate(-10, -10);
        g.FillEllipse(Brushes.LightGreen, bounds);
        g.DrawEllipse(Pens.Black, bounds);
    }
}

private void drawButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    _doCustomDrawing = true;
    drawPanel.Invalidate();
}

private void drawPanel_Resize(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    drawPanel.Invalidate();
}
```

## But why?  What was I doing wrong, and how does this fix it?

Take a look at the [documentation for Control.CreateGraphics](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.creategraphics%28v=vs.110%29.aspx):

> The Graphics object that you retrieve through the CreateGraphics method should not normally be retained after the current Windows message has been processed, because anything painted with that object will be erased with the next WM_PAINT message.

Windows doesn't take responsibility for retaining the graphics you draw to your `Control`.  Rather, it identifies situations in which your control will require a repaint and informs it with a WM_PAINT message.  Then it's up to your control to repaint itself.  This happens in the `OnPaint` method, which you can override if you subclass `Control` or one of its subclasses.  If you're not subclassing, you can still do custom drawing by handling the public `Paint` event, which a control will fire near the end of its `OnPaint` method.  This is where you want to hook in, to make sure your graphics get redrawn every time the `Control` is told to repaint.  Otherwise, part or all of your control will be painted over to the control's default appearance.

Repainting happens when all or part of a control is *invalidated*.  You can invalidate the entire control, requesting a full repaint, by calling `Control.Invalidate()`.  Other situations may require only a partial repaint.  If Windows determines that only part of a `Control` needs to be repainted, the `PaintEventArgs` you receive will have a non-empty `ClipRegion`.  In this situation, your drawing will only affect the area in the `ClipRegion`, even if you try to draw to areas outside that region.  This is why the call to `drawPanel.Invalidate()` was required in the above example.  Because the appearance of `drawPanel` needs to change with the size of the control and only the new parts of the control are invalidated when the window is expanded, it's necessary to request a full repaint with each resize.

Comment: +1. This is nice info I was looking for.  I had doubts about `CreateGraphics` and now I understand much better how drawing works in Winforms.