# draw Cross at application start C#

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, drawing

I am trying to draw a cross inside of a Windows Forms App.

I can do it using two lines. I have tested it using a Button.
Now I do not know how I can draw it automatically when opening the application without pressing a button.

thanks for ur help :D

Comment: [Form.Load Event](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.form.load%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

Comment: @EBrown that doesn't work...

Comment: I recommend against `Form.Load` because anything drawn there will be overwritten in later `Paint` events.  I recommend adding a `Paint` event handler and doing your drawing there using the provided Graphics object from the `PaintEventArgs`.  See more here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30419493/drawing-glitches-when-using-creategraphics-rather-than-paint-event-handler-for-c

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Good practice is override your form `OnPaint` method and do all paintings you need there (using `Graphics` object from `e.Graphics`):

```
protected override void OnPaint(PaintEventArgs e)
{
    base.OnPaint(e);

    //your paintings here
}
```

Otherwise, if you will place your painting code somewhere else (Load, Shown and so on) - your paintings will not be done automatically when your form will be redrawn by system.

Comment: Well said.  Succinct and accurate.

Answer (score -2):

Just invoke the method inside a InitializeComponent()

Every form has its own constructor
you can see it in the project tree, {formname}.Designer.cs press F7

and there you just see the constructor

so just invoke it there

```
 private void InitializeComponent()
    {
        this.components = new System.ComponentModel.Container();
        this.AutoScaleMode = System.Windows.Forms.AutoScaleMode.Font;
        this.Text = "Form1";
    }
```

Comment: I don't think the form will necessarily have a window handle by the end of the constructor, and you need a window handle to do any drawing.  Also, `InitializeComponent` is not the constructor and it is "owned" by the designer, which means any changes you make to the code in `InitializeComponent` will be overwritten when you make changes in the designer.

Comment: Even so, any drawing done here will be erased the next time the form is refreshed or another window is dragged across it.