# How to Bring the Border of a Picturebox to Front?

Tags: c#, winforms, border, panel, picturebox

I am making a border around a picture box by simply drawing a rectangle around it. However since there is a panel behind the picturebox, I cannot see the border around the picturebox (despite the fact that I have drawn the border around the picture. Here's the code:

```
private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        this.WindowState = FormWindowState.Maximized;
        Graphics objGraphics = null;
        objGraphics = this.CreateGraphics();
        objGraphics.Clear(SystemColors.Control);
        objGraphics.DrawRectangle(Pens.Blue,
             ileriresmi.Left - 1, ileriresmi.Top - 1,
              ileriresmi.Width + 1, ileriresmi.Height + 1);
        objGraphics.Dispose();
    }
```

Comment: Did you try to use `Panel.CreateGraphics()` instead of `this.CreateGraphics`, and did you also add this implementation to your `Paint` event handler? Otherwise your drawn border will instantly disappear, when the form gets repainted (e.g. by resizing it or placing another window infront of it)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you may try this..but it will draw inside the picture box

```
 private void pictureBox1_Paint(object sender, PaintEventArgs e)
        {


            e.Graphics.DrawRectangle(new Pen(Color.Red, 2f),0,0,pictureBox1.Size.Width-2, pictureBox1.Size.Height-2);


        }
```

Complete solution will be like this.
add this class into your application and build application.

```
  public class PicExt : PictureBox
    {
        private Color _borderColor;
        private int _borderWidth;
        [Browsable(true)]
        public Color BorderColor { 
            get { return _borderColor; } 
            set { _borderColor = value; this.Invalidate(); } 
        }
        [Browsable(true)]
        public int BorderWidth {
            get { return _borderWidth; }
            set { _borderWidth = value; this.Invalidate(); }
        }

        public PicExt()
        {
            _borderColor = Color.Red;
            _borderWidth = 3;

        }

        protected override void OnPaint(PaintEventArgs pe)
        {
            base.OnPaint(pe);
            pe.Graphics.DrawRectangle(new Pen(BorderColor, BorderWidth), BorderWidth, BorderWidth, this.Size.Width - (BorderWidth*2), this.Size.Height - (BorderWidth*2));
        }
    }
```

after building application you will see new control "PicExt" in your toolbox.
replace pictureBox with PicExt Control
and subscribe the click event like this.

```
 private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            //set the color here
            picExt1.BorderColor = Color.Red;
            //and frame width 
            picExt1.BorderWidth = 5;
        }
```

it should work like exactly you want.

Comment: thanks and how do i change the border color when i click on the picturebox? I copied the same method to picturebox1_click method but it gives this error: Error 5 'System.EventArgs' does not contain a definition for 'objGraphics2' and no extension method 'objGraphics2' accepting a first argument of type 'System.EventArgs' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

Comment: In the Click() handler, just change the BorderColor property: `pictureBox1.BorderColor = Color.Green;`

Answer (score 0):

There are a couple things wrong here.  First, you're doing your drawing on the form, which is covered by the panel you mention, and second, you're only drawing the border once, in the `Load` event, rather than every time the form receives a WM_PAINT message.

See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30419493/drawing-glitches-when-using-creategraphics-rather-than-paint-event-handler-for-c) for an explanation of why the latter is wrong.

As for getting the border drawn in the right place, why not just set the `BackColor` of the panel that holds the `PictureBox` to `Color.Blue` and give that panel a nonzero value for `Padding`?  (Or, if the panel contains other controls, add an intermediate panel just for the border.)