# How to draw an ellipse in a form when clicking in the form?

Tags: c#, winforms, visual-studio, graphics

I know it sounds simple but i never worked with Visual studio and I just can't get it. I'm using

```
private void Usecasediagram_Paint_elipse(object sender, PaintEventArgs e)
{
    System.Drawing.Graphics graphicsObj;

    graphicsObj = this.CreateGraphics();

    Pen myPen = new Pen(System.Drawing.Color.Green, 5);
    Rectangle myRectangle = new Rectangle(100, 100, 250, 200);
    graphicsObj.DrawEllipse(myPen, myRectangle);
}
```

To draw this ellipse when the code runs but I want it to appear only when I click somewhere in the form and this circle to appear in the mouse location. I already got the click method of the form working but I don't know how to call that function like what to pass in pass in PaintEventArgs...

Comment: You're not going to want to do it this way in the end.  Take a look this for why: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30419493/drawing-glitches-when-using-creategraphics-rather-than-paint-event-handler-for-c

Answer (score 2):

Store the infomation about what you want to draw at Form/Class level, and use the [Paint() Event](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.paint%28v=vs.110%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396) which supplies its own `Graphics` via `e.Graphics`

If you want **one** ellipse, then:

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{

    private Point DrawEllipseAt;
    private bool DrawEllipse = false;

    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        this.Paint += Form1_Paint1;
        this.Click += Form1_Click;
    }

    private void Form1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        this.DrawEllipseAt = this.PointToClient(Cursor.Position);
        this.DrawEllipse = true;
        this.Invalidate();
    }

    private void Form1_Paint1(object sender, PaintEventArgs e)
    {
        if (this.DrawEllipse)
        {
            Graphics G = e.Graphics;
            Rectangle myRectangle = new Rectangle(DrawEllipseAt, new Size(0, 0));
            myRectangle.Inflate(new Size(125, 100));
            using (Pen myPen = new Pen(System.Drawing.Color.Green, 5))
            {
                G.DrawEllipse(myPen, myRectangle);
            }
        }
    }

}
```

If you want **multiple** ellipses:

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{

    private List<Point> DrawEllipsesAt = new List<Point>();

    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        this.Paint += Form1_Paint1;
        this.Click += Form1_Click;
    }

    private void Form1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        this.DrawEllipsesAt.Add(this.PointToClient(Cursor.Position));
        this.Invalidate();
    }

    private void Form1_Paint1(object sender, PaintEventArgs e)
    {
        Graphics G = e.Graphics;
        if (this.DrawEllipsesAt.Count > 0)
        {
            using (Pen myPen = new Pen(System.Drawing.Color.Green, 5))
            {
                foreach (Point pt in this.DrawEllipsesAt)
                {
                    Rectangle myRectangle = new Rectangle(pt, new Size(0, 0));
                    myRectangle.Inflate(new Size(125, 100));
                    G.DrawEllipse(myPen, myRectangle);
                }
            }
        }
    }

}
```