# How to detect if mouse has clicked inside of a certain shape in c# on winform app?

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, picturebox

Let's say that I have a win form app and I have a picture box called pictureBox1. Then I run the following code:

```
public System.Drawing.Graphics graphics;
public System.Drawing.Pen blackPen = new System.Drawing.Pen(Color.Black, 2);

public void drawVennDiagram()
{
    graphics = pictureBox1.CreateGraphics();
    graphics.DrawEllipse(blackPen, 0, 0, 100, 100);
    graphics.DrawEllipse(blackPen, 55, 0, 100, 100);
}
```

If I call `drawVennDiagram()` , it will draw two circles in `pictureBox1` and the circles overlap just enough to look like a venn diagram.

What I am trying to achieve is as follows:

> - Run Method `A` if the mouse clicks anywhere outside of the venn diagram but in the picturebox.
> - Run Method `B` if the mouse clicks only inside of the first circle.
> - Run Method `C` if the mouse clicks inside of both circles.
> - Run Method `D` if the mouse clicks only inside of the second circle.

So far I have written the code below, which essentially tracks where the cursor clicks, but I have no way of figuring out which parameter (a, b, c, d) the cursor location follows.

```
private void pictureBox1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    this.Cursor = new Cursor(Cursor.Current.Handle);
    int xCoordinate = Cursor.Position.X;
    int yCoordinate = Cursor.Position.Y;
}

private void pictureBox1_MouseUp(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
{
    int xCoordinate = e.X;
    int yCoordinate = e.Y;
}
```

What is the best way to achieve this?

Comment: The simplest way will be to use GraphicsPath(s), which has ready functions to test this.

Comment: Also: Using CreateGraphics is a serious mistake!! Store the coordinates and draw either in the Paint event of into a Bitmap!!!

Comment: Well, what is wrong with using CreateGraphics? Does it slow down the processing time or something?

Comment: No, it is not about slowing things down. It is a basic newbie mistake you absolutly need to correct. The problem is about drawing your graphics in a persistent way. Try to miminize and maximize the application to see what I mean. Every day a dozen questions come up here: Why does my drawing disappear.. Also note the the math gets rather nasty when you need to use ellipses and even more so once you want to rotate them.

Comment: I keep a canonical question around that explains why not to use `CreateGraphics`.  It's here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30419493/drawing-glitches-when-using-creategraphics-rather-than-paint-event-handler-for-c

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes. Given a circle is positioned with center *(x<sub>c</sub>,y<sub>c</sub>)* and radius *r*, a coordinate *(x,y)* is within the circle if: *(x-x<sub>c</sub>)<sup>2</sup>+(y-y<sub>c</sub>)<sup>2</sup>≤r<sup>2</sup>*.

Given we know that, we also know that your circles have a center at *(50,50)* and *(105,50)* and each have a radius of *50*. So now we define a method:

```
public static bool InsideCircle (int xc, int yc, int r, int x, int y) {
    int dx = xc-x;
    int dy = yc-y;
    return dx*dx+dy*dy <= r*r;
}
```

Now you can use:

```
private void pictureBox1_MouseUp(object sender, MouseEventArgs e) {
    int x = e.X;
    int y = e.Y;
    bool inA = InsideCircle(50,50,50,x,y);
    bool inB = InsideCircle(105,50,50,x,y);
    if(inA && inB) {
        C();
    } else if(inA) {
        B();
    } else if(inB) {
        D();
    } else {
        A();
    }
}
```

Note however that for now, the two circles you paint do not overlap anyway.

Answer (score 4):

You can use [`GraphicsPath`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.drawing.drawing2d.graphicspath(v=vs.110).aspx) and `AddXXXX`  methods like [`AddEllipse`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/21sfy33s(v=vs.110).aspx) to create the shape and then use [`IsVisible`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/d20k495d(v=vs.110).aspx) method to check if the given `Point` is in the shape.

For example:

```
public bool Contains(Rectangle ellipse, Point location)
{
    var contains = false;
    using(var gp= new System.Drawing.Drawing2D.GraphicsPath())
    {
        gp.AddEllipse(ellipse);
        contains = gp.IsVisible(location);
    }
    return contains;
}
```

Using this idea you can check for all kind of shapes.

Answer (score 2):

You can tell whether a point falls inside a circle by testing whether the distance from the point to the circle's center is less than the circle's radius.  In your example, the first circle has a center of (50,50) and a radius of 50.  To test whether the clicked point is within 50 pixels of the circle's center, do this:

```
private void pictureBox1_MouseUp(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
{
    double xdiff = e.X - 50;
    double ydiff = e.Y - 50;
    double dist = Math.Sqrt(xdiff * xdiff + ydiff * ydiff);
    if (dist <= 50)
    {
      // do something here
    }
}
```

Comment: I like that idea, but how would I test how far away the cursor is from the center point of the circle?

Comment: FYI, @WillemVanOnsem's answer is more efficient because it avoids calculating the square root by working with the square of the radius rather than the radius.

Comment: I'm not the greatest mathmatician, but okay I will take both of your advice. :)

Comment: @TaW, in fairness, the OP is trying to draw Venn diagrams, which probably won't involve ellipses, rotated or otherwise.  But it's true that in the general case of testing whether a point is contained by a closed path, the `GraphicsPath` solution is more broadly applicable.

Comment: [Venn diagram](http://images.google.de/imgres?imgurl=https%3A%2F%2Fupload.wikimedia.org%2Fwikipedia%2Fcommons%2F1%2F10%2FSymmetrical_5-set_Venn_diagram.svg&imgrefurl=https%3A%2F%2Fcommons.wikimedia.org%2Fwiki%2FFile%3ASymmetrical_5-set_Venn_diagram.svg&h=742&w=746&tbnid=QlMwzViqYItLvM%3A&docid=eX35dDoaChmxCM&ei=7LGJVvUJgf9orvScsAw&tbm=isch&iact=rc&uact=3&dur=2143&page=2&start=20&ndsp=20&ved=0ahUKEwj1r_346I7KAhWBPxoKHS46B8YQrQMIYjAU)