# Drawing graphics when creating a new object

Tags: c#, drawing

I played with some custom Controls created by me and I wanted to draw some Graphics for them.

I achieved everything I wanted but I have a question because something seems strange to me.
I tried for example to make a new control like this:

```
public class Square : Control
{
    public Square(Point location)
    {
        this.Size = new Size(100, 100);
        this.Location = location;
        Draw();
    }

    public void Draw()
    {
        Graphics g = this.CreateGraphics();
        g.DrawRectangle(Pens.Black, 5, 5, 20, 20);
    }
}
```

This doesn't draw anything, but, if I call the "Draw" method from another action like a button press on the form it works.
It also works if I override the OnPaint method of my control and call the "Draw" method here. (I know that I should make all the drawing in the Paint/OnPaint but I did this just to try other things)

What's the difference ? Why can't I just call my "Draw" method anywhere I want?

Comment: Presumably the drawing done by the `Draw()` call is overwritten by the first `OnPaint` call.  And calling it in a button click handler will only "work" until part or all of the control is invalidated and `OnPaint` is called, which will again overwrite what you drew in `Draw`.  This is the reason for the rule about only drawing in `OnPaint`.  See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30419493/drawing-glitches-when-using-creategraphics-rather-than-paint-event-handler-for-c.

Comment: You can simply follow [msdn](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/b818z6z6(v=vs.110).aspx) (quote: *"When inheriting from the `Control` class, you must override the `OnPaint` method"*). Who told you your approach should work? It won't.

Comment: Now I understand! Awesome explanation :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you call `Draw()` method in constructor, the control has not yet been added to the parent, is just an object in memory, so the call has no effect.

If you make the call as you say in the `OnPaint()` method, then is drawed since this method is called whenever render the control is needed.

Comment: Thanks for the answer! I got it know.