# C# Graphics.Drawline function not working, "The name 'graphics' does not exist in the current context"

Tags: c#, namespaces

I am creating my first visual C# program. I am trying to get to grips with drawing graphs/lines, however I am getting the error "the name 'graphics' does not exist in the current context".

This is the entirety of my program:

```
public Form1()
{

    InitializeComponent();

    Pen blackPen = new Pen(Color.Black, 3);

    Point point1 = new Point(100, 100);
    Point point2 = new Point(500, 100);

    graphics.DrawLine(blackPen, point1, point2);
}
```

Google tells me that the `graphics.DrawLine` function is within the `System.Drawing` namespace that I have already included.

Apologies if this is a simple question as this is very much my "hello world".

Comment: Proper way to create the Graphics objects is described in the MSDN article [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/5y289054(v=vs.110).aspx).

Comment: The artivle is not bad but __not good__ either. It fails to make clear that anythig drawn with a graphics from control.CreateGraphics will not __persist__

Answer (score 4):

You could add an event handler to Paint event of the form, having code something like below:

```
    private void Form1_Paint(object sender, PaintEventArgs e)
    {
        Pen redPen = new Pen(Color.Red, 30);

        Point point1 = new Point(0, 0);
        Point point2 = new Point(500, 500);

        e.Graphics.DrawLine(redPen, point1, point2);

        redPen.Dispose();
    }
```

And not trying to do the drawing in the form constructor. So move the code from the constructor to this event handler.

Comment: Don't forget call **Dispose** on the Pen object.

Comment: @Jackdaw  Yeap, the code can be improved having this Dispose call, good remark ! I updated the  code.

Comment: Thankyou very much for this answer...I have included your function in the Form1 class, however when I run the application it does not seem to do anything. Is there any other action that needs to be taken?

Comment: You're welcome, you should check that the code is the event handler of the "Paint" event of the Form. So select your form then click on the Events tab, then in the "Appearance" category double click the "Paint" event, that will create the event handler of the "Paint" event in that event handler add the code from example's event handler.

Answer (score 1):

You're probably working from examples you've seen online where the `Graphics` object is provided as a parameter to a method or defined outside of the code shown.  `Graphics` objects can draw to a variety of targets--the screen, an image, a printer....  You should figure where you want your graphics to go; how to initialize or get a reference to the appropriate `Graphics` object will depend on this.  For instance, if you want a simple way to draw to the screen, add a `Paint` event handler to a `Form` via the Windows Forms Designer.  When the event fires, you'll get a `PaintEventArgs` object that has a property called `Graphics`.  Use this to do your drawing.

Answer (score -1):

You're declaring Graphics as a local variable within your constructor. You probably would rather declare it as an instance first, then assign it inside the constructor.

Answer (score -1):

The issue appears to be that you haven't declared the `graphics` variable. I think you need something like:

```
public Form1() {
    InitializeComponent();

    Pen blackPen = new Pen(Color.Black, 3);

    Point point1 = new Point(100, 100);
    Point point2 = new Point(500, 100);

    Graphics graphics = CreateGraphics();
    graphics.DrawLine(blackPen, point1, point2);
}
```

The extra line here creates a new graphics object on the current form which you can use to draw the line.

Comment: This is a bad way to draw to a form.  See [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30419493/drawing-glitches-when-using-creategraphics-rather-than-paint-event-handler-for-c) for why.

Comment: @adv12 This is a "Hello World" my first app type of thing, no point trying to preach best practice, the issue is about trying to use a variable that's not declared.

Comment: the issue *was* about trying to use a variable that's not declared; now it's about why the graphics don't get redrawn when the window is occluded, resized, or dragged offscreen.  Your answer trades a compilation error for a bug.