# C# - PictureBox Graphic flickering

Tags: c#, graphics

I try to make an animated Ball like PingPong, it is working but there are the graphic flickerings. I searched throw the web nothing helped me. I have double buffered the form and I tried it with Drawing with bitmaps but then the Ball wont show.
Here my Code for the ball animation:

```
        protected PictureBox pictureBox;
    protected Graphics graphics;
    //
    public MoveBall(PictureBox pictureBox)
    {
        this.pictureBox = pictureBox;
        graphics = pictureBox.CreateGraphics();
    }
    //
    public void AnimateBall(List<Point> positions, Ball ball)
    {
        foreach (Point point in positions)
        {
            graphics.FillEllipse(new SolidBrush(pictureBox.BackColor), new Rectangle(ball.Position.X - Convert.ToInt32(Convert.ToDouble(ball.Width) * 0.5), ball.Position.Y - Convert.ToInt32(Convert.ToDouble(ball.Height) * 0.5), ball.Width, ball.Height));
            ball.Position = point;
            graphics.FillEllipse(new SolidBrush(ball.Color), new Rectangle(point.X - Convert.ToInt32(Convert.ToDouble(ball.Width) * 0.5), point.Y - Convert.ToInt32(Convert.ToDouble(ball.Height) * 0.5), ball.Width, ball.Height));
            Thread.Sleep(1);
        }
    }
```

Comment: Use the Paint event and get rid of `CreateGraphics` and the Graphics object

Comment: And use a Timer instead of `Thread.Sleep`.

Comment: Do as @Plutonix says, and use Invalidate() to force a repaint.  Also, never sleep the UI thread.

Comment: It would be *very difficult* to do any research on this using SO posts and not have already encountered this advice

Comment: But how can I do that?

Comment: Do *what*?  Search SO for good code / the right way to paint?

Comment: I searched for it but nothing helped me. so I ask no here.

Comment: @RageSkilln, [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30419493/drawing-glitches-when-using-creategraphics-rather-than-paint-event-handler-for-c) is a Q&A that may help you.

Comment: Ok but how can help me the paint event when the user doesnt draw anything or do the code looks like