# Image Drawing with Graphics C#

Tags: c#, graphics, bitmap

I want to draw a image in a picture box, and the image is not drawing what is wrong with my code? Thanks

```
        Bitmap b;
    private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {


        b = new Bitmap(1000, 100);
        pictureBox1.Image = b;
        Graphics g = pictureBox1.CreateGraphics();
        Rectangle rect = new Rectangle(20, 20, 70, 70);
        Image earth =  Image.FromFile("" + System.IO.Directory.GetCurrentDirectory() + @"\earth.png");
        g.DrawImage(earth,rect);



    }
```

Comment: Never use CreateGraphics.  Use the Paint event of the PictureBox instead to get the graphic object.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`Form.Load` fires before anything is drawn to the screen.  When the `Form` is actually displayed for the first time, `PictureBox.OnPaint` will be called and the control will render itself with its default appearance.  To properly draw to a `PictureBox`, handle its `Paint` event and do your drawing in the event handler using the supplied `Graphics` instance.  That event will be fired every time any part of the control is redrawn, which will allow you to draw graphics that persist when the control is invalidated.  See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30419493/drawing-glitches-when-using-creategraphics-rather-than-paint-event-handler-for-c) for more information.

Comment: thanks,  i fixed it, so to draw the image i need to press a button on something the Graphics.DrawImage dose not work on form load.

Comment: Sorry, I don't understand your question.  In your constructor (or via the designer), add an event handler to your control's `Paint` event handler.  Then, in the handler method, do your drawing.  The user shouldn't need to click a button or anything for this to work.