# How can I redraw the graph?

Tags: c#, graph, drawing

My program just prints a graph. 
if I move my form outside the screen, my graph isn't printed. How can I fix it? I am a begginer in it.
Can you help with it?
Thank you.

```
    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
       Graphics gr ;
       int m11, m12, m21, m22, dx, dy, ax, ay;
        gr = pictureBox1.CreateGraphics();
        int xmin = -5;
        int xmax = 10;
        int ymin = 0;
        int ymax = xmax * xmax;

        ax = pictureBox1.Size.Width / (xmax - xmin);
        ay = pictureBox1.Size.Height / (ymax - ymin);
        m11 = ax;
        m12 = 0;
        m21 = 0;
        m22 = -ay;
        dx = -xmin * ax;
        dy = pictureBox1.Size.Height - ay * (-ymin);

        System.Drawing.Drawing2D.Matrix M = new 
        System.Drawing.Drawing2D.Matrix(m11, m12, m21, m22, dx, dy);
        gr.Transform = M;
        int x = 0;
        for (x = xmin; x < xmax; x++)
        {
            System.Drawing.Point p1 = new System.Drawing.Point(x, x * x);
            System.Drawing.Point p2 = new System.Drawing.Point(x + 1, (x + 1) * (x + 1));
            float brushSize = 0.2F;
            System.Drawing.Pen pen = new 
            System.Drawing.Pen(System.Drawing.Brushes.Black, brushSize);
            gr.DrawLine(pen, p1, p2);

        }
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Drawing glitches when using CreateGraphics rather than Paint event handler for custom drawing](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30419493/drawing-glitches-when-using-creategraphics-rather-than-paint-event-handler-for-c)

Comment: Don't use `CreateGraphics`. Instead, use the `Paint` event.

Comment: Number 24 today. Never do this: System.Drawing.Graphics formGraphics = this.CreateGraphics();. Winforms graphics basic rule #1 : Never use control.CreateGraphics! (also never try to cache a Graphics object! Either draw into a Bitmap bmp using a Graphics g = Graphics.FromImage(bmp) or) draw in the Paint event of a control, using the e.Graphics parameter.