# How to draw a rounded checker on a checkerboard with C#?

Tags: c#, winforms

I have an online checkers game project and I have a problem with drawing the checkers on the panel array elements. The checkerboard pattern is drawn in the form's onload event. I have a method to draw a circle and fill the same circle to create a round shape on each checkerboard square but my form is just showing the squares with no checker pieces on them.

**Code**

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace Checkers
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        private Panel[,] _chessBoardPanels;
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }
        /*This method is supposed to draw a circle which later should be 
          filled by the method that follows*/
        public static void drawCircle(Graphics g,Pen pen,float centerX,float centerY, float radius)
        {
            g.DrawEllipse(pen, centerX - radius, centerY - radius,
                      radius + radius, radius + radius);
        }
        /*This method fills a circle drawn above on the panel with the desired color
           
         */
        public static void fillCircle(Graphics g, Brush b, float centerX, float centerY, float radius)
        {
            g.FillEllipse(b, centerX - radius, centerY - radius,
                     radius + radius, radius + radius);
        }
        private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
           //controls the size of a single square on the checkerboard
            const int tileSize = 100;
           //controls the number of squares on either side of the board
            const int gridSize = 8;
           //this is fr applying different colors to the board so the pattern is realized
            var clr1 = Color.DarkGray;
            var clr2 = Color.White;

            // initialize the "chess board"
            _chessBoardPanels = new Panel[gridSize, gridSize];

            // double for loop to handle all rows and columns
            for (var n = 0; n < gridSize; n++)
            {
                for (var m = 0; m < gridSize; m++)
                {
                    // create new Panel control which will be one 
                    // chess board tile
                    var newPanel = new Panel
                    {
                        Size = new Size(tileSize, tileSize),
                        Location = new Point(tileSize * n, tileSize * m)
                    };
                    //get the graphics context from each panel and store in g
                    Graphics g = newPanel.CreateGraphics();
                    //instantiate a pen
                    Pen penner = new Pen(Brushes.Black, 3);
                    //defining the center of the circle 
                    float cx = newPanel.Width / 2;
                    float cy = newPanel.Height / 2;
                     //defining the radius of the circle
                    float radius = cx / 2;

                    // add to Form's Controls so that they show up
                    Controls.Add(newPanel);

                    // add to our 2d array of panels for future use
                    _chessBoardPanels[n, m] = newPanel;

                    // color the backgrounds
                    if (n % 2 == 0)
                        newPanel.BackColor = m % 2 != 0 ? clr1 : clr2;
                    
                    else
                        newPanel.BackColor = m % 2 != 0 ? clr2 : clr1;
                    //draw a new checker piece if this is true
                    if (n % 2 == 0)
                        drawCircle(g, penner, cx, cy, radius);
                    else
                        ;
                }
            }
           
        }
    }


}
```

Any help to help me draw a circle and fill it so that the image of a checker piece on the board is realized is welcome.
Object oriented solutions are also welcome involving the `class Checkers`, This is because it would be easier to write methods to move the checker piece to a certain panel on the board with ease.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Drawing glitches when using CreateGraphics rather than Paint event handler for custom drawing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30419493/drawing-glitches-when-using-creategraphics-rather-than-paint-event-handler-for-c)

Comment: @adv12, no it does not, I need an object oriented solution involving the class checker, which I will attach a newPanel.Click event to move it to the target event panel

Comment: You will still need to follow the GDI drawing rules which basically forbid you to use control.CreateGraphics() if you want persistenz results. This has nothing to do with OOP. - The way to go is code the Paint event of the control, make sure it is double-buffered and trigger the Paint event by calling Invalidate on the control. Can be done nicely in yozr class..

Comment: @Taw, okay agreed, what changes do you propose I make to my code to make it use a paint event to draw the circle and fill it?

Comment: The place to do drawing in a Windows Forms app is in the `Paint` event handler. Keep the state of the board (the _model_) somewhere, and whenever the Paint event happens, redraw the entire form from the model. Whenever a piece is moved or removed, `Invalidate` the rectangle that contains (or contained) the piece. It takes a while to get used to this programming model (logic in on place, drawing in a completely different place), but it works well

Comment: @Flydog57, I like you man. Simply put, let me try to execute the instructions you have put across.

Comment: You don't need to figure out what parts of the model to draw in the `Paint` handler; just draw the entire board.  If you manage invalidation correctly, then only the changed parts will actually be redrawn.

Comment: @Flydog57, so my code is correct? Its supposed to draw the ellipse but its not because am not using invalidate and `control.Paint.Graphics` event to paint?

Comment: @Flydog57, thanks man it drew the ellipse when I attached a Paint event handler to redraw the shape, thanks man. I had a good feeling you were going to solve this.

Comment: @Everyone, I will come back when I need to program the AI for this game and the Machine Learning section, Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Following helpful comments on the original answer, I realized you need to use a `Control.Paint` event to draw the circles on the squares.

**Code**

```
public class Checkerpiece
    {
        //colors of the rounded pieces
        Color color;
        //specify where the checker is drawn
        Panel target_square;
        //specify the center of the circle
        float center_x;
        float center_y;
        //specify the radius of the checker piece
        float radii;
        //fill the details inside the constructor
        public Checkerpiece(Panel mypanel,Color color)
        {
            this.color = color;
            this.target_square = mypanel;
            this.center_x = mypanel.Width / 2;
            this.center_y = mypanel.Height / 2;
            this.radii = mypanel.Width / 2;
        }
        //this method draws the checkerpiece on the target panel
        public void draw()
        {
            this.target_square.Paint += Target_square_Paint;
            
        }
        //this event will redraw the circles as needed
        private void Target_square_Paint(object sender, PaintEventArgs e)
        {
            
            Pen mypen = new Pen(color, 3);
            drawCircle(e.Graphics, mypen, this.center_x, this.center_y, this.radii);

        }

        public static void drawCircle(Graphics g, Pen pen, float centerX, float centerY, float radius)
        {
            g.DrawEllipse(pen, centerX - radius, centerY - radius,
                      radius + radius, radius + radius);
        }

    }
```

**Output**

[image]