# c# fill an image with color using byte array

Tags: c#, arrays

So this is driving me insane. I'm trying to fill my whole picture box with color using a byte array but I can't seem to figure out where to end my fors. If I set them to the dimensions of the bmp it doesn't cover the whole thing, not even close.

Please help. Here's the code this far

```
    using System;
    using System.Collections.Generic;
    using System.ComponentModel;
    using System.Data;
    using System.Drawing;
    using System.Linq;
    using System.Text;
    using System.Threading.Tasks;
    using System.Windows.Forms;
    using System.IO;
    using System.Drawing.Imaging;
    
    
    namespace TEST_
    {
        public partial class Form1 : Form
        {
            public Form1()
            {
                InitializeComponent();
            }
    
            byte[] BitmapData_From_Bitmap(Bitmap bmp)
            {
                MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream();
                bmp.Save(ms, ImageFormat.Bmp);
                return (ms.GetBuffer());
            }
            Bitmap Bitmap_From_BitmapData(byte[] bmpData)
            {
                MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream(bmpData);
                return (new Bitmap(ms));
            }
            void set_color(byte[] byte_array, int rezO, Color col, int l, int c)
            {
                byte_array[54+4 * c + 4 * l *rezO] = col.B;
                byte_array[ 54+4 * c + 4 * l * rezO + 1] = col.G;
                byte_array[54+4 * c + 4 * l * rezO + 2] = col.R;
                byte_array[ 54+4 * c + 4 * l * rezO+3] = col.A;
            }
          
            private void p_MouseDown(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
            {
       
                Graphics g = p.CreateGraphics();
                Bitmap bmp = new Bitmap(p.Width, p.Height, g);
                byte[]  byte_array = BitmapData_From_Bitmap(bmp);
    
                int rezO = Convert.ToInt32(bmp.HorizontalResolution);
    
                for (int i = 0; i <bmp.Height; i++)
                {
                    for (int j = 0;j<bmp.Width;j++)
                    {
                        set_color(byte_array, rezO,Color.Red, i, j);
                        
                    }
                }
              
                bmp = Bitmap_From_BitmapData(byte_array);
                g.DrawImage(bmp, 0, 0);

            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: Since you use `rezO` as the stride of the image in pixels, it should be `bmp.Width`, and not `Convert.ToInt32(bmp.HorizontalResolution)`  which is in pixels per inch.

Comment: In: `Graphics g = p.CreateGraphics();` where/how is `p` defined?

Comment: bmp.Save() in BitmapData_From_Bitmap will save the Bitmap to the stream in the Windows  .BMP format, which will not be raw pixel data.  There are headers and all the stuff you would expect in a format that has to convey what sort of data it contains.  You are probably looking for Bitmap.LockBits and Bitmap.UnlockBits.  https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.drawing.bitmap.lockbits?view=dotnet-plat-ext-6.0

Comment: When calculating a 2-d index into an array, you need the width: `int pixel = 54 + 4 * (l * width + c) + 0;` (Assuming 54 is the size of the bitmap header.) The `4` is for 4-bytes-per-pixel. And you would increment the last `0` for b,g,r,a. And I don't think `rez0` is needed.

Comment: @Rook's answer correctly addresses the Bitmap manipulation, but since you're really just trying to fill the PictureBox with Color.Red, why not just g.Clear(Color.Red)?

Comment: Also you really don't want to be doing your drawing using CreateGraphics().  You need to be able to repaint the control at any time with a saved state, as it can be invalidated for a number of reasons.  See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30419493/drawing-glitches-when-using-creategraphics-rather-than-paint-event-handler-for-c

Comment: @Luuk p is the picture box

Comment: @adv12 YES but I don't really know how to incorporate them here...

Comment: @adv12 also because I need it for a bigger purpose. The goal is to code something that allows me to fill certain spaces in the picturebox, just like paint but this is just an intermediate step

Answer (score 3):

Your pixel-wrangling routine is all kinds of bad, but rather than pick that apart, I'll just point out that you're going about accessing the raw bytes of a bitmap in the hardest possible way.

Consider this instead:

```cs
// note use of 'using'... if you don't dispose of the bitmap 
// after you've drawn it, you'll have memory leakage issues
using Bitmap bmp = new Bitmap(p.Width, p.Height, g);

// you might not need this if you know you'll always 
// be using 32bpp pixel formats or whatever.
var bytesPerPixel = bmp.PixelFormat switch
{
    PixelFormat.Format32bppArgb => 4,
    PixelFormat.Format24bppRgb => 3,
    _ => throw new NotSupportedException()
};

// BitmapData is the correct way to access the raw bytes of an image
var bits = bmp.LockBits(
    new Rectangle(0, 0, bmp.Width, bmp.Height), 
    ImageLockMode.ReadWrite, 
    bmp.PixelFormat);

try
{
    for (var y = 0; y < bits.Height; y++)
    {
        // we need a raw pointer here, and that means we need
        // an unsafe block
        unsafe
        {
            // the stride of an image can sometimes be longer than the
            // number of actual pixel bytes in a row
            var row = new Span<byte>(
                (bits.Scan0 + y * bits.Stride).ToPointer(), 
                bits.Width * bytesPerPixel);

            for (int p = 0; p < row.Length; p += bytesPerPixel)
            {
                var someColour = Color.Red;

                row[p + 0] = someColour.B;
                row[p + 1] = someColour.G;
                row[p + 2] = someColour.R;

                if (bytesPerPixel == 4)
                    row[p + 3] = someColour.A;
            }
        }
    }
}
finally
{
    // always unlock the bits when you're done.
    bmp.UnlockBits(bits);
}
```

Note that:

- I'm using `BitmapData.Scan0` to get a pointer to the raw bytes underlying the bitmap, rather than hacking around with saving an image to a memory stream.
- I'm using a `Span<byte>` to access the raw memory, as it is slightly less hazardous to do so than to mess about with raw pointer access and arithmetic.
- I'm not using anything like `HorizontalResolution`. That's a value in eg. dots-per-inch, and is of no use to you here at all.
- I'm using `bits.Stride` to know how many bytes are found in a row. This is because non-32bpp images (eg. plain 24bpp RGB) can have extra padding bytes at the end of each row that aren't part of any pixels.
- I'm not creating new bitmaps... I'm modifying the one I started with.
- I'm disposing of my bitmap when I'm finished with it so I don't leak memory.

If you know your image always has the same pixel format, you can do things like this:

```cs
struct PixelBgra
{
    public byte B, G, R, A;
}
```

and create your span like this:

```cs
// note that I'm not using `bytesPerPixel` anymore, 
// because I'm using a struct of the right size
var row = new Span<PixelBgra>((bits.Scan0 + y * bits.Stride).ToPointer(), bits.Width);

for (var x = 0; x < row.Length; x++)
{
    row[x].R = someColour.R;
    // etc
}
```

Comment: Hi, I really appreciate your suggestion and all your explanations and I do understand that my code is all kinds of messed up but still :)) do you think you can point me to some kind of solution that would incorporate those functions? They're written by my teacher and I kind of need to use them for a project. I would really appreciate it.